# Opencart 2.0.3.1 ошибка с обновлением модификаторов

Tags: opencart

Возникла странная ошибка после установки модуля [OCJazz] SeoPro. После того как я обновляю модификаторы, падает сайт с многочисленными ошибками.
В самой админке получаю такой текст.
Opencart 2.0.3.1

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input in E:\OpenServer\domains\vfirma.dev\admin\controller\extension\modification.php on line 141Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in E:\OpenServer\domains\vfirma.dev\admin\controller\extension\modification.php on line 144
Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in E:\OpenServer\domains\vfirma.dev\admin\controller\extension\modification.php on line 154
```

Не нашел пока решения, гугл никаких актуальных данных не дает. Может кто сталкивался с этим?

Answer (score 1):

В модификаторах. Сначала я выключил Pavo Framework 3.0 (он мешал). нажал обновить. Всё включилось. Потом обратно включил Pavo Framework 3.0
У Вас вместо Pavo Framework 3.0 может другое что-то, что препятствует обновлению :)